# Degenerate Dimension in multiple fact tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-warehouse

I am working off an ERD diagram to add a new aspect to our data warehouse. While reviewing the design I noticed a few dimensions that could have their values moved to existing dimensions and the natural keys converted to degenerate dimensions in the fact. After reviewing the document a little further these dimensions exist because the natural keys are required for more then 1 fact table. I have been going back and forth with the designer and he insists they need to be actual dimensions so that the 2 fact tables can use the conformed dimension for reporting/analytics.

The grain of the fact and dimension tables are slightly different. For example, the fact table contains a record for each line (think orderID and OrderLine) and the dimension only has a record for each header (think OrderID). The dimensions tend to have roughly 3/4 of the records that exist in the fact table. The main thing that really bugs me is that our fact and dimensions have the same name "dimXXXX and factXXXX".

For this type of scenario what is best practice?

Comment: I'd post this to dba.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: I generally move as much info into the fact table - and have a similar fact table with Order + Order Line information in it and I do not have a Order Header type dimension (though I considered it).  A conformed dimension implies that different fact tables will use the dimension for analysis - what are the other fact tables that use the Order Header dimension?  I followed Kimball verbatim for my order fact table: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/